# Why are all of my Socket.io connection id's prefixed with "/#"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Basically, I've never noticed this before but for some reason every socket.io connection that I receive on my node server is prefixed with "/#". Example:

[image: node cmd line]

Notice every single id starts with a /#

Here is the code from the server that outputs that line:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas? If this is now normal then I'm ok with this, but it seems like it could be an issue in the future.

Cheers,
Cam

Answer (score 0):

The '#' is the socket ID (which you can think of as individual names unique to each socket client). In the screenshot, you can see that each client is tagged with a unique hashed ID, which is generated automatically every time a client connects to a socket.io server.

Socket IDs are a great way to keep track of individual responses (like displaying usernames in a chat) that a client may emit to a server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply :) I understand that they are socket ID's, I just want to know is it standard to see the "/#" before it? I had never noticed it before...